# How to avoid use od StringHolder class in Java?

Tags: java, spring

I have a following endpoint:

```
@GetMapping("/{campaign}")
@SneakyThrows
public S3StringHolder downloadRawFactDataS3(@PathVariable Integer campaign) {
    String selectDataQuery = new RawFactSelectTemplate(campaign).translate().getSqlQuery();
    //todo: find some way to do it on object mapper level
    return new StringHolder(service.downloadDataFilledTemplate(campaign, selectDataQuery));
}
```

StringHolderClass

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class StringHolder {
    private String fileS3Id;
}
```

I use StringHolder only because i need to return here not just a simple string with service.downloadDataFilledTemplate(campaignId, selectDataQuery) method call result, but a json which will look like:

```
{
fileS3Id: "hereSomeText"
}
```

Is there some possible good-looking ways to avoid usage of StringHolder class still preserving the structure of output JSON?

Comment: Well, you could create a `Map<String, String>`, call `put("fileS3Id", "someText")` and serialize that to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid wrapping your String in a Class you could make your controller return a Map<String, String> and then return:

```
return Collections.singletonMap("key", myText)
```